# Using context receiver on a delegated property

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-context-receivers

I have a property delegate using a context receiver:

```
class LoggingPropertyDelegate<T, V, L : Log>(
    private var value: V,
    private val toLog: T.() -> L
) : ReadWriteProperty<T, V> {
    override fun getValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>) = value

    context(Logger)
    override fun setValue(thisRef: T, property: KProperty<*>, value: V) {
        this.value = value
        log(toLog(thisRef))
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it on a property:

```
var myValue: Int by LoggingPropertyDelegate(0, { InfoLog("Changed to $myValue") })
```

I get an error that there is no suitable `set` functions for the delegate. If I remove the context from the method everything works as expected.

Is it not possible to use context receivers on property delegates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* possible to use a property delegate that has context receivers. You just need to provide the context receiver in some way.

First, note that you should put `context(Logger)` on the delegate class type, not on `setValue`:

```
context(Logger)
class LoggingPropertyDelegate<T, V, L : Log>(
```

If `myValue` is an instance property of some class `Foo`, then you can do:

```
context(Logger)
class Foo {
    var myValue: Int by LoggingPropertyDelegate(0) { ... }
}
```

Note that if `Foo` is a data class, there seems to be a compiler bug that causes the compiler to crash. Perhaps context receivers are lowered to extra compiler parameters (?)

And then when instantiating `Foo`, you will need to provide a `Logger`:

```
val foo = with(someLogger) { Foo() }
// now you can access foo.myValue
```

(or instantiate `Foo` in another function with a `Logger` context receiver, of course)

If `myValue` is a local variable, you can also directly use `with` to introduce the context receiver instance, in addition to adding a `Logger` context receiver to the enclosing function.

Comment: I thought only the caller would need to "pass" the context when using the variable, I didn't think of declaring it on my class :) Thanks!

Comment: This seemed to resolve the issue as IntelliJ no longer showed an error, but when I tried to run it, it did not work, it breaks the Kotlin compiler. I posted the complete solution here: https://pastebin.com/erfdsLZx and stack trace here: https://pastebin.com/9guWH0UP

Comment: @alturkovic That is most definitely a compiler bug. Looks like I really should hit "compile" before posting lol. But the fix is simple - just move `context(Logger)` to the property delegate class (see the edit).

Comment: I don't think moving the `context(Logger)` to the class instead of the `setValue` works either: https://pastebin.com/g7WQu2PB

Comment: @alturkovic After some investigation, it seems like the compiler bug is related to `Example` being a data class. If you change `Example` to a regular class, it works. I recommend reporting this bug on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT.

Comment: @alturkovic See https://pl.kotl.in/EvWUtwjT6